# Ayuda: identificar tipo de oración subordinada

Tags: sintaxis

¿Podríais echarle un vistazo a esta frase por favor?

*Hizo lo posible porque no lo viera nadie que pudiera compadecerlo.*

**porque no lo viera nadie** – es una oración final ¿verdad?
(la conjunción *porque* no tiene un valor causal sino final ¿o me equivoco?

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente, es una clásula final (aunque la cláusula completa sería "porque no lo viera nadie que pudiera compadecerlo", ya que "que pudiera compadecerlo" modifica a "nadie" y por tanto es dependiente de este, que es a su vez sujeto de "viera").

Según el [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=por+que), "porque" puede ser una conjunción final:

> **porque.** 1b: También se emplea como conjunción final, seguida de un verbo en subjuntivo, con sentido equivalente a *para que: «Hará lo que pueda porque su estancia en Suecia sea feliz»* (Sampedro *Congreso* [Esp. 1952]). En este caso se admite también su escritura en dos palabras: *«Hará lo posible por que se cure»* (Marías *Corazón* [Esp. 1992]).

Comment: Cuidado, porque ese «por que» es separado. Y yo la veo claramente final, igual que si dijera «para que».